# Invalid null pointer error when converting std::chrono::system_clock::time_point::min() to string

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, stl, c++-chrono

I am following an example in Nicolai M. Josuttis' "The C++ Standard Library (Second Edition)", page 152-153, which details an example to print the epoch, current time, minimum and maximum times of the `std::chrono::system_clock` introduced in C++11.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, and get an assertion triggered in `<xstring>`, due to an invalid null pointer. This occurs on the line `std::string ts = std::ctime( &t )` in the code below after setting `tp = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point::min();`

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string asString( const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& tp )
{
    std::time_t t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t( tp );
    std::string ts = std::ctime( &t );
    ts.resize( ts.size()-1 );
    return ts;
}

int main()
{
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp;
    std::cout << "epoch: " << asString(tp) << std::endl;

    tp = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "now: " << asString(tp) << std::endl;

    tp = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point::min();
    std::cout << "min: " << asString(tp) << std::endl;

    tp = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point::max();
    std::cout << "max: " << asString(tp) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is this due to an implementation error by Dinkumware in the `<chrono>` library, or just a typo/mistake in the book? I have gone over the code given in the book again and again to see if I have copied it out incorrectly, but this does not appear to be the case. I'd be very grateful for any insights given.

Comment: Well, how about checking for errors? `ctime` has a well-defined interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `std::ctime` returns NULL, which indicates an incorrect `t` value. Probably because the call to `asString` uses a value of `time_point` that cannot be represented in `time_t` type.

Comment: Why would this be the case though? In Dinkumware's implementation `time_t` is a typedef for `__int64` (a 64-bit signed integer), so whilst `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point::min()` results in a negative `time_t` I cannot find anywhere which states that the argument for `std::ctime` must be a pointer to a non-negative `time_t` value?

Comment: `min()` returns minimum duration. If it's say 1 nanosecond it probably cannot be represented in `time_t`. What is `t` value after `to_time_t()`?

Comment: The debugger states that `t = -922337203684`, which I guess could be too large (in absolute value) for `std::ctime`?

Comment: Yes, I guess `ctime` cannot handle this. I am not sure about MS VC's implementation, but usually time_t is a number of seconds elapsed since 01.01.1970. For this value of 't', it's something like year 28 000 B.C.